# Keys.DELETE of Action class in selenium is not deleted

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am sending an element from DOM:

```
action = new Actions(webDriver);
action.moveToElement(el);
action.click(element).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a", Keys.DELETE));
```

and after this command sending this 'filledText' which is the text itself as a string, say "login":

```
action.sendKeys(filledText).build().perform();
```

But for some reason, the field is filled with the "a" before the filled text. I get "alogin".

Comment: Try to use Keys.BACKSPACE to clear text.

Comment: Instead of DELETE?

Comment: Yes. If your string length >1 , use BACKSPACE with for loop.

Comment: Can you send an example please? what is this row does any way?  "            action.click(el).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a", Keys.BACK_SPACE));
"

Answer (score 0):

Try to sendKeys in two steps without ActionsChains.

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
element.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
```

OR use Backspace with for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<string_length ;i++)
{
    element.sendKeys(Keys.BACKSPACE);
}
```

Comment: what is the "a" for?

Comment: "Control + A" to select all text.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> in first step to select the all text and then <kbd>delete</kbd> in second step to remove the text.

```
Actions action = new Actions(webDriver);
action.moveToElement(el);
action.click(element).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
```

And then

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
```

You can also use <kbd>backspace</kbd> to clear the text using loop

```
WebElement textboxName = driver.findElement(By.locator);
int textLength = textboxName.getText().length();

while(textLength!=0)
{
    textboxName.click();
    textboxName.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
    textLength = textboxName.getText().length();
}
```

I personally experienced that due to some complex DOM structure sometime Selenium `clear()` method doesn't work. You can try below alternative :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(loc);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.click(element).sendKeys(Keys.END).keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys(Keys.HOME).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).perform();
```